# STL container to pop() by priority?

Tags: c++, qt, stl

I'm writing a thread-pool for Qt as `QRunnable` doesn't handle event loops in new threads.

Not too familiar with STL, what would be the best way to pop() something by priority?  Priority should probably be a property of `MyRunnable` imo, but I can always give that info to an STL container when adding the runnable to the queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with QT, but as other suggest, use a `priority_queue`.

You'll also need a functor to allow the structure to access the priority information and specify the sorting order.

```
struct is_higher_priority {
    bool operator()( MyRunnable const &l, MyRunnable const &b )
        { return l.priority > r.priority; }
};

std::priority_queue< MyRunnable, std::deque<MyRunnable>, is_higher_priority > q;

...

q.push( task_1 );
q.push( task_2 );
q.push( task_3 );

MyRunnable &highest = q.top();
highest.run();
q.pop();
```

Comment: But don't use non-atomic `top`/`pop` combination in a multithreaded program.

Answer (score 4):

By `pop()` I'm assuming you want some sort of a stack structure. I'm unsure how to achieve that with stack semantics, but the priority issues could be solved simply with  `std::priority_queue`.

Answer (score 3):

The standard library has `std::priority_queue`, which is, as its name suggests, a generic priority queue implementation.

Comment: +1. I don't know why my answer has more upvotes than yours :( They seem to say the same thing.